# Could someone look at my code and tell me what's wrong?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I am trying to get this simple program to work but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; I tried making a new file to see if the problem was with my syntax but it's still happening. Here it is:

```
public class test {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

     String operator = args[0];

     switch(operator) {

     case "*":
     System.out.println("Hello");
     break; 

             }
         }
     }
```

I'm trying to run this program on my terminal by first doing

```
  $ javac test.java
```

and then actually running the program along with the argument

```
  $ java test *
```

and I get nothing after that, any reason why? It seems to work when "*" is replaced with "+".

I also noticed that it would only work if I typed out

```
  $ java test "*" //notice the quotation marks
```

Why does the asterisk without the parenthesis not work even though it is a string but "+" without the parenthesis works? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: [Globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Comment: By parentheses, do you mean quotation marks?

Comment: Printing the value of `operator` before the switch could help you see what's going on. (Elliot's comment)

Comment: @River Yes I meant asterisks, whoops.

Comment: @asterisks? `*` <- asterisk `"` <-quotation mark `()` <-parentheses

Comment: At least on the mac, `*` has a special meaning, it passes the contents of the directory to the command, with each file been a argument

Comment: @River oh my goodness gracious I am out of it right now; I meant the quotation marks that is surrounding the asterisk. So sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is nothing to do with Java.  The problem happens because the shell will treat the `*` character as a filename pattern and expand it to the names of all files in the current directory.

The solution is to escape the `*` character **on the command line**.  There is nothing that you can do in Java to solve this.

---

There are a three ways that will work as escaping (for a POSIX compliant shell)

```
    java test "*"
    java test '*'
    java test \*
```

There may be other obscure ways to do this .... but the above should suffice.

(The difference between `"*"` and `'*'` is that they escape different shell constructs.  Double quotes disable just "globbing" of file pathnames.  Single quotes also disable parameter substitution and other things.)

Characters that *may* be need to be escaped if you use them in command line arguments include:

- `*`, `?`, `[`, `]`, `~`, `{`, `}` - used in globbing, etc
- `$` - parameter substitution
- shell symbols `|`, `&`, `;`
- `#` - the comment character
- the backquote character.

You should refer to a tutorial or textboox on the shell, or read the manual entry for the shell you are using.

Comment: What do you mean escape the * ? As in choose another symbol in replace of the asterisk?